# Making changes in configuration of a jenkins job using Job DSL plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-job-dsl

I am dynamically creating new job in jenkins when a new branch is created in BitBucket. These jobs are copy of an existing "template_job". Now I want to update the configuration of "Branches to Build" and my workspace. Below is the code to create a new job using the template job.

```
job(branch_name) {
    using('template_job')
}
```

I am using the below code to update my branch to build.

```
job(branch_name) {
    using('template_job')
    scm {
        git {
            branch(branch_name)
        }
    }
}
```

But this is erasing all the contents in configuration. Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCM configuration can not be updated partially.

But you can use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to update the relevant parts of the config XML:

```
job('example') {
  using('template_job')
  configure { node ->
    node / scm / branches / 'hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec' / name('bar')
  }
}
```

Comment: how to do the same in case of multiple SCM selection in Jenkins?